# How do we compare the performance of different ConvNets?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently training a net to play a game with a CNN having the following architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(100, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(classifications, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now I wish to introduce some complexity in the architecture and make the net deep. How can I tabulate the performance of the CNNs of different complexities and ultimately conclude by giving the best choice for the particular task?

Am i going in the wrong direction? How to decide the depth of a CNN and how does it affect the performance on the same dataset?

Thanks in advance (I am new to this site, kindly excuse the immaturity of this post)

Edit: Information about the dataset I am using: dataset consists of images and each image has 3 possible lables (0, 1, 2) stored in a CSV file with each row corresponding to that particular image.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is generate a few different model architectures, train them on a train set and evaluate them on the test set. Then compare their accuracies and the one with the highest accuracy should in theory be the best performing model.

To make the model deeper you can add extra dense or convolutional layers. For example:

changing this:

```
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
```

to this:

```
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
```

will add three extra dense layers. Hence making the network deeper.

You can do the same with duplicating the convolutional layers by duplicating the Conv2D and MaxPooling2D lines.

The alternative to 'trial and error' approach to finding the best architecture and hyperparameters is to use a search approach [like explained in this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/) that user grid search. It will, however, take significantly longer than just trying out a few versions you can up with yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Is there some kind of intuition developers make while adding more layers? Can these results (obtained by adding more layers randomly) make the net perform better? Can these results be tabulated and serve as research work or is it just too novice?

Comment: For starters I would suggest looking at current architectures like resnet or inception to see what works well and then experiment by modifying it. The way current state of the art models are compared is by evaluating them on a same dataset like the COCO dataset and, although not easy, if you get better results than the current models you could most certainly publish a paper about it.

Comment: Can we scale down these already trained networks to train on the dataset which I have prepared for playing a game?

Comment: if you're referring to retraining the already trained networks to solve your own problem (playing a game in your case), then that's definitely doable and a common practice. It's called transfer learning. It's described pretty well here https://medium.com/@14prakash/transfer-learning-using-keras-d804b2e04ef8

Comment: My dataset has like 5000 images (270*160) (grayscale) and I wish to compare results of training on different CNN architectures (2 pre trained and 1 (mine) which will just repeat Conv, pooling and dense layers 3-4 times). Should I go ahead with this idea for writing a paper or am I going in a wrong direction?